# How to resolve a failed Plesk update?

Tags: centos5

I have a dedicated server running CentOS 5.3. I'm trying to update Plesk 9.5.2 to version 10.0.0 but update fails. I do it with yum:

```
yum update psa* --skip-broken -t
```

but it fails and I get the errors at the end:

```
Skip-broken could not solve problems
Error: plesk-mail-pc-driver conflicts with psa-qmail
Error: plesk-mail-pc-driver conflicts with psa-qmail-rblsmtpd
Error: plesk-mail-qc-driver conflicts with plesk-mail-pc-driver
Error: plesk-core conflicts with plesk-billing
Error: Missing Dependency: sw-engine = 2.0 is needed by package plesk-billing-6.0.4-20090625.11.noarch (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: pp-sitebuilder >= 10.3.0 is needed by package psa-10.3.0-cos5.build1012110629.18.x86_64 (plesk)
Error: plesk-mail-pc-driver conflicts with plesk-mail-qc-driver
```

Is there a way that I could solve this?

Comment: How do you **want** to solve this? Which of the conflicting packages do you want to eliminate?

Comment: I'm not even sure what those packages mean.

Comment: Isn't this the question you have to ask yourself? And trying to force something you don't know with `--skip-broken` is not a good option, is it? Better question to yourself: Why updating when it's working?

Comment: I have to update because I'm switching servers and I need 100% compatibility (Plesk 10 is on the old server)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Just used this autoinstaller and everything worked fine:

```
parallels_installer_v3.10.0_build110701.11_os_CentOS_5_x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue 2 days ago - I had to update from 9.2.2 via `SSH` to 9.5.4 then remove sitebuilder before it allowed me to update to 10.3.1 - works great now and has the updated sitebuilder on not that its used! The best way is probably what @Caballero said but this was useful for me and may help some one else out.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting the server and update the Plesk using the autoinstaller or GUI Updater.

You can also check the migration with http://kb.parallels.com/en/9436